# How to prove functions to be Lipschitz only in bounded closed domain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

> Question. If $X\left(x,t\right)$ has continuous partial derivatives on a bounded closed area/set $\mathscr{D}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}$, then prove or disprove that $X$ is a Lipschitz function for variable $x$.

I'm reading a lemma about prove a function to be Lipschitz, the lemma declared in a convex set $\mathscr{D}$ and used the mean value theorem. But what I'm thinking is: If "the convexity" is necessity? I know that the derivative of $X$ is bounded in the domain, but without the convexity, we cannot use the mean value theorem here. Intuitively, this seems correct.

---

thanks for anyone's answer before, I studied for hours for a satisfactory answer of this question, and I got a sophisticated counterexample, this counterexample constructed from cantor set, and modified many times to satisfied the condition sharply in 1 dimension. I rearranged my construction to make it more readable, please check and I will close this question.

suppose $k_{n}=2^{n}$, $l_{n}=1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$(generally, I just suppose $k_n\to\infty$, $l_n\to 1$ in my draft), for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, when $x\in\left[\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{2k_{n}-l_{n}-1}{2^{n+1}\left(k_{n}-l_{n}\right)}\right]$,
define $f\left(x\right)=l_{n}\left(x-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, $f\left(0\right)=0$ to ensure that the domain of $f$ is closed, and $f\left(x\right)$ undefined for other $x$. easy to checked the derivative of each point in the domain other than $x=0$ is exists. Also $f'\left(0\right)=1$ is easy to check by the definition:

$$f'\left(0\right)=\lim_{D\left(f\right)\ni x\to0}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}=\lim_{n\to\infty,x\in I_{n}}\frac{l_{n}\left(x-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{x}=1,\quad I_{n}=\left[\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{2k_{n}-l_{n}-1}{2^{n+1}\left(k_{n}-l_{n}\right)}\right].$$

But, the difference quotients of the function f at endpoints of each interval is unbound, that is $$\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)-f\left(\frac{2k_{n}-l_{n}-1}{2^{n+1}\left(k_{n}-l_{n}\right)}\right)}{\frac{1}{2^{n}}-\frac{2k_{n}-l_{n}-1}{2^{n+1}\left(k_{n}-l_{n}\right)}}=k_{n}\to\infty$$ as this counterexample is designed by this equation. I drawed a picture of this function using MMA as follows:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "closed domain"? (This is puzzling because usually a "domain" is an open set by definition...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich oh, what i want to say is that the domain can be closed. the definition of a domain is open set seems only in complex analysis. when we say the domain of a function, it could be closed. i slightly modified my question.

Comment: If $D$ is just a bounded closed set it might have empty interior, in which case I have no idea what the definition of the partial derivatives might be.

Comment: use the definition on discrete set $\mathrm{Dom}(f)$ as $f'(x_0)=\lim_{{x\to x_0}\atop{x\in \mathrm{Dom}(f)}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$, here $\mathrm{Dom}(f)$ is the domain of function $f$. I think there is such a definition in some book, but didn't remember that.

Comment: Yeah, but what if $x_0$ is an isolated point of $D$ (meaning there are no "nearby" points of $D$)? Then $\lim_{D\ni x\to x_0}$ doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes, there is no derivatives at an isolated point for any function, the limiting point should be dropped in $D$, I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } -1 \le x \le 1 \text{ and } -1 \le y \le 0 \\
1 & \text{when } 0 < x \le 1 \text{ and } x \le y \le 2x \\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

This satisfies all of the condition *except* convexity of the domain, at least if "has partial derivatives" means something it is *possible* for a function on a bounded closed set to satisfy. But it is not even continuous at the origin, and so in particular not Lipschitz.

---

**Whoops.** This is not really a counterexample because it doesn't have a definite $\partial f/\partial x$ at the point $(1,2)$. In one sense, this is a "boring" way to fail, because it is far from the point of real interest at the origin, so we can easily fix it by restricting everything to $y\le1.9$.

On the other hand, it doesn't really feel worth it to fix the example, because this very failure showcases that *it is unexpectedly hard* for a function to have all partial derivatives everywhere when it is defined on a closed bounded subset.

This means that the *corrected* claim

> Suppose $f$ is defined on a closed, bounded, convex subset of $\mathbb R^m$ and that $f$ has continuous partial derivatives everywhere. Then $f$ is Lipschitz.

is, even though it is true, not a very interesting result for $m\ge 2$ because there are very few functions that satisfy the assumption. In particular, every $f$ that satisfies it can be made to *stop* satisfying it just by rotating the coordinate system by a random angle. It doesn't even apply to a *constant* function defined on the closed unit disk.

(See the comment thread where David C. Ullrich discusses various proposals for salvaging the claim).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if a function has continuous partial derivatives, it must be continuous.

Comment: but your function can not be differentiated at $(0,0)$, the derivative at $(0,0)$ does not exists, its directional derivative is $0$ from below, $\infty$ from above.

Comment: yes, you are right, this is no business with directional derivative. the partial derivatives is continuous for each variable.

Comment: Say the domain of that function is $K$. It seems to me that $f$ has partial derivatives at every point of $K$ in a less problematic sense: There exists $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such that $g$ has partial derivatives at every point of $\Bbb R^2$ and $g|_K=f$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: That's an interesting condition. Unfortunately I think it is so liberal that it makes the claim in the question (where partial derivatives exist and are continuous on a closed convex subset $K$) false. For example suppose $g(0,0)=0$ and $g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\sin 2\theta$ for $r>0$, and then take $K = \{(x,x)\mid -1\le x\le 1\}$. Now $g$ has partial derivatives everywhere, and they are identically zero on $K$ (so in particular continuous on $K$), but $g|_K$ is again not even continuous.

Comment: Good point. My view is we should just go ahead and call  it false, and restrict the positive result to _open_ convex sets...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: There are different problems with the claim when the domain is an _open_ convex set -- when the set is not compact we can't be sure that the partial derivatives are bounded just because they're continuous. For example, in a single dimension $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is not Lipschitz on the bounded open convex set $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Well of course - the result I had in mind talks about Lipschitzness on compact subsets of that open convex set - of course there has to be compactness somewhere...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Hmm, then I think I agree to the truth of your variant. But does "convex" still serve a purpose in that case?

Comment: Actually I'm suddenly not so sure of the result. First, for the obvious proof I have in mind I want to assume $K$ is a convex compact subset of the domain. Then write $f(q)-f(p)$ as the integral over $[p,q]$ of\dots except oops, assuming just that the partials restricted to $K$ are continuous does not give us the chain rule for $\phi(t)=f(a+tb)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It's even worse than I thought -- see amended answer. I now think the only _nice_ way to salvage this would be to drop the talk of continuous _partial_ derivatives completely and instead assume up front that the function is $\mathcal C^1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to clarify something in the example Henning posted in another  answer. The notion of "has partial derivatives" is somewhat problematic there (not his fault!); in fact his function has partial derivatives in a standard and totally non-problematic sense.

Say $f$ is the function in that answer and $K$ is the domain of $f$.

> > There exists $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such that $g$ has partial derivatives everywhere and $g|_K=f$.

Indeed, there exists a ($2\pi$-periodic) $C^\infty$ function $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that if we define $g(0,0)=0$ and $g(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))=\phi(t)$ for $r>0$ then $g|_K=f$ and also $g(0,y)=0$ for all $y$.

So $g$ is smooth away from the origin. It's not continuous at the origin, but that doesn't matter; since $g(x,0)=0$ and $g(0,y)=0$ it has partial derivatives at the origin.